# Cant Add Shape (image)

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am trying to add a image to my code but it keep raising the error

> Bad arguments for register_shape

I am following the tutorial at http://blog.trinket.io/using-images-in-turtle-programs/

my code is:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

# click the image icon in the top right of the code window to see
# which images are available in this trinket
image = "C:\...\rocketship.png"

# add the shape first then set the turtle shape
screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
```

I am using python 2.6.
furthermore when I use the function of

> screen.bgpic("C:...\Backgrounds\giphy2.gif")

The background works.

Comment: `r"C:\Users\--myName--\Desktop\Python\FinalPrj\Space\images\Backgrounds\giphy2.gif"` — add an `r` prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look for answers here:
[How can i add an image (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427742/how-can-i-add-an-image-python)

> The turtle module does have support for images, but only GIF images, not PNG or any other format. As the docs for addshape say:
>
> > name is the name of a gif-file and shape is None: Install the corresponding image shape.