# adding an image to the Turtle Screen

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

How can I add image to my `Turtle Screen` using turtle graphics?

whenever I use the function `addshape` I keep getting errors.

does turtle graphics got any other way loading/importing images?

for example:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

image = r"C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Python\rocketship.png"

screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/turtle.html) module does have support for images, but only GIF images, not PNG or any other format. As the docs for [`addshape`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.addshape) say:

> *name* is the name of a gif-file and shape is `None`: Install the corresponding image shape.

And if you look at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/lib-tk/turtle.py#l825), they're serious about "gif-file": the way it decides whether you're trying to add an image or a polygon is by calling `data.lower().endswith(".gif")`, which obviously won't work for `.png` files.

And, even if you fix that, it will still only be able to handle the file formats that [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/tkinter.html) supports out of the box, which includes some extra things like PPM/PGM/PBM, but still not PNG. If you want to support PNG files, you'll want to install [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) as well.

At this point, you're getting beyond what people usually do with `turtle`. That might be worth pursuing (you'll learn a lot by doing so), but it may be simpler to use an image-converting program to convert the `.png` file to a `.gif` file so it will work with your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use gif files with Python Turtle.  Take any picture and convert/resize for free at ezgif.com.

Background:

```
win = turtle.Screen()

win.bgpic('background.gif')
```

Using shapes:

```
win.register_shape('pic1.gif')

sprite = turtle.Turtle()

sprite.shape('pic1.gif')
```

Example game:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q49Xyo0LYDs