# How can I import an image in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, image, import, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

What I want, is to get an image to replace the default turtle, just like it is done here: http://blog.trinket.io/using-images-in-turtle-programs/.

This is my code, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
import turtle

image = "C:/Python27/Pythonprogramming/image.png"
screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.addshape(image)
turtle.shape(image)

turtle.mainloop()
```

This is all in effort to make a turtle that's actions can be manipulated through Python code. I have searched all over the internet, but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding an image to the Turtle Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427742/adding-an-image-to-the-turtle-screen)

Answer (score 2):

The turtle graphics has support for *.gif* images only. Please try to change your image's format.

Here's a link to a similar question [How can i add an image (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427742/how-can-i-add-an-image-python)

Answer (score -1):

Trinket is a program for python! You have to type your code in trinket if you want that code to work!

Comment: Maybe you could add a short example to your answer.

Comment: I don't think this applies to OP. They probably already are running their code in trinket.

Answer (score -1):

this picture must be in the same folder with **doc.py** . And then you can write name of the picture: **img.gif**

Comment: It's true that the image needs to be a gif, but it'd be best if you provided actual code to load the image (as other answers already do).