# Python Turtle Custom Shape Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427786/3042018) and still can't get a custom shape to work for Python Turtle.

My code is here:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.register_shape('car', 'car.gif')

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('car')
```

I'm getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_type'` but I don't know why. The image is a genuine .gif as required.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it correct.  When registering a polygon, you give it a name, but when registering a GIF image, you use the image's name:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.register_shape('car.gif')

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shape('car.gif')

screen.mainloop()
```