# How to make a turtle's shape an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

I want to make a small game with my own image for the turtle's shape. I've put both the program and the image in the same directory. Whenever I run the code it says:

---

File "C:\Users\Nobody PC\Desktop\THE PROJECT.py", line 51, in 
    p.shape('beara')
  File "C:\Users\Nobody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2777, in shape
    self.turtle._setshape(name)
  File "C:\Users\Nobody\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\turtle.py", line 2493, in _setshape
    if self._type == "polygon" == screen._shapes[shapeIndex]._type:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_type'

---

My code includes nothing about a string (I think):

---

```
import turtle as t
bear =  "bear.png"
p = t.Turtle()
t.register_shape('beara',bear)
t.bgcolor('black')
p.shape('beara')
```

---

I made it:

```
t.register_shape('beara',"bear.png")
```

but still had the same error.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape), that's not how you use the function.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of a png file, I should've used a gif file?

Comment: Yes, use a gif and make it the first (and only) parameter.

Comment: I guess I got confused between introducing/ making a shape and introducing an image. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding an image to the Turtle Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427742/adding-an-image-to-the-turtle-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using a PNG instead of a GIF, you're not invoking the turtle methods correctly.  I'll force OOP syntax, instead of the function syntax you used, to make the method ownership clearer:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

image = "bear.gif"

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.register_shape(image)

turtle = Turtle(shape=image)

# ...

screen.mainloop()
```

Note that when using images as cursors, the name of the file is the name of the shape, you don't define your own name for it (unlike polygons.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that turtle module accepts ,png as a shape you must use a gif image. in your code just replace the image with a gif image and hope it will work
check this out ....

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.addshape('shap1.gif')


t.shape('shap1.gif')
screen.mainloop()
```