# How to create intricate custom shapes in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to code a chess game, and I'm making each piece a turtle and because I need to them to move I need to create a custom shape that is made with many intricate parts. Is there an easier way than doing turtle.register_shape() with a bunch of coordinates in it

I would prefer a more simple code, I tried using file.gif and uploading a gif and registering that picture as a shape but I have no idea how to do that. And I don't think it works on the website I use for coding, replit.

Comment: I currently don't have any, been researching for an hour and nothing has worked, or I don't understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding an image to the Turtle Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427742/adding-an-image-to-the-turtle-screen)

Comment: "I tried using file.gif and uploading a gif and registering that picture as a shape" -- there's no code from this attempt?

Comment: There was no place for me to add a link or do any code it just said "Failed to load media file."